# Python Queue put(), get() in one loop Time limit Exceeded

Tags: python-3.x, sliding-window

I am calculating the moving average of all integers in the sliding window by using Queue. However I got TLE when I want to first get the number from Queue add to sum and then put it back. I think it is because of my for loop,anyone can help?

```
import queue

class MovingAverage:
    """
    @param: size: An integer
    """
    def __init__(self, size):
        # do intialization if necessary
        self.q = queue.Queue(size)

    """
    @param: val: An integer
    @return:  
    """
    def next(self, val):
        # write your code here
        if self.q.qsize() > 3:
            self.q.get()

        self.q.put(val)
        a = 0
        **for _ in range(self.q.qsize()):
            n = self.q.get()
            a += n 
            self.q.put(n)**

        return a
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong tool here. The [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) module in general and [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) in particular are intended for use in multithreaded programs! In a single threaded program, you can't add items beyond its `maxsize`. From its docs:

> Insertion will block once this size has been reached, until queue items are consumed.

This blocking will simply halt your program on the first `put` beyond `maxsize`.

You should rather use e.g. a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque). Furthermore, you should improve your algorithm. A moving average (or moving sum, according to your code) does not have to (re)iterate the entire window all the time...

For instance:

```
from collections import deque

class MovingAverage:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.q = deque()
        self.a = 0
        self.size = size

    def next(self, val):
        if len(self.q) == self.size:
            self.a -= self.q.popleft()
        self.q.append(val)
        self.a += val
        return self.a
        # or, for the average
        return self.a / len(self.q)

>>> m = MovingAverage(3)
>>> m.next(1)
1.0
>>> m.next(2)
1.5
>>> m.next(3)
2.0
>>> m.next(4)
3.0
>>> m.next(5)
4.0
>>> m.next(1)
3.3333333333333335
>>> m.next(1)
2.3333333333333335
>>> m.next(1)
1.0
```

Comment: Got it,actually what I thought was , in the for loop,since I use 'get()' and then 'put()',so I firstly deleted the number in the Queue and then added back. So I thought this would not exceed its max size.